# Showing dropdownlist in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this constant in my rails project

```
   ID_METHODS = {      
          :category => [
              "name 1",
              "name 2",
              "name 3"
              "name 4",
              "name 5",
              "name 6"
              "name 7",
              "name 8",
              "name 9"
          ]
      }
```

and show them in dropdownlist using following code

```
<%= f.select :id_methods, CategoryConstants::ID_METHODS[:staff].collect { |i| [i, i] }, {include_blank: "Select"} -%>
```

This results output

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 4
name 5
name 6
name 7
name 8
name 9
```

But I need to output in the dropdownlist like below

```
name 1
 name 2
 name 3
  name 4
  name 5
name 6
name 7 
 name 8
 name 9
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `grouped_options_for_select`

Ex.

```
 collection = ["North America",[["United States","US"],["Canada","CA"]]]
```

then

```
<%= select_tag(::id_methods, grouped_options_for_select(collection, selected_key = " ", prompt = nil)) %>
```

Please detail [click](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select)

Comment: with grouped options for select subcategory show only two level but I need them in 4 level